# Add html in *ng-for loop in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add html code from a variable inside a for loop in angular 2:

```
<ul>
   <li *ng-for="#c of myHtmlItems">
      {{c.myHtml}}
   </li> 
</ul>
```

The html is only added as a string

Comment: In alpha.52 ng-for becomes ngFor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do:

```
<ul>
    <li *ng-for="#c of myHtmlItems" inner-html="{{c.myHtml}}></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works but removes all other html already exists in the child node

Comment: you could create element inside li, eq. div and set it's inner html

Comment: I have other tags (x3dom) and only mentioned <ul> as an example. But it works for now. Thanks.

Comment: In alpha.52 ng-for becomes ngFor

Answer (score 4):

## Update to angular2.0.0

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let c of myHtmlItems" [innerHTML]='c.myHtml'></li>
</ul>
```

1. *ng-for has been replaced with *ngFor
2. `#` has been replaced with `let`
3. inner-html with innerHTML
   (better to use property binding like this `[innerHTML]='c.myHtml'` instead of `inner-html="{{c.myHtml}}`)

Answer (score -2):

instead of ng-for, give a try with ng-repeat. As mostly ng-repeat is useful in very different ways

```
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="element in myHtmlItems">
            {{element}}
         </li> 
      </ul>
```

Comment: DOM elements can be repeated with ng-repeat

Comment: ng-repeat in Angular 2? your code still has *ng-for

Comment: it is from angular version 1.